# Unable to resolve module ../../App from /Users/jordancuff/dev/app10-react-native/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner programmer and everything was going great until I kept getting the following message.

Unable to resolve module ../../App from /Users/jordancuff/dev/app10-react-native/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js:

- App(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)

  - App/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
    1 | import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
    2 |

> 3 | import App from '../../App';
> |                  ^
> 4 |
> 5 | registerRootComponent(App);
> 6 |

This is happening on every project I create now. Can anybody assist?

Comment: Can you do a `npm i` and make sure all the packages are installed correctly?

Comment: Okay whenever I move the App.js file out of the App folder it works